# Remove individual pictures by size

Tags: c#

I have a folder with images and i would like to delete some of the images by size. Unfortunately, i can’t use the File.Delete(string) method. What should I do to fix this error?

```
            string pathName = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Images\";
            DirectoryInfo dir_info = new DirectoryInfo(pathName);

            foreach (FileInfo filo in dir_info.GetFiles())
            {  
               Bitmap img = new Bitmap(filo.FullName);

               int width =  img.Width;
               int height = img.Height;

               int H = 90;
               int W = 136;
 
               if ((height >= H) && (width >= W))
               {    
                 File.Delete(filo.FullName);
               }                

            }
```

Comment: What error?  It's probably because you're trying to delete the file without disposing of `img`; wrap it in a `using` block.

Comment: How does this work? Could you help me, please? Thank you

Comment: You haven't told us what the error is. But you could also use `fileo.Delete`. Also, instead of loading every image, it may be faster to just look at the header manually: [width is an `int32` at byte 12, height at byte 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)

Comment: I figuered it out, Charlieface. I think, Lance is right. You have to wrap the code in a using block and use simply  img. Dispose()